# how to delete specific rows from a specific variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, delete-row

I'm trying to delete specific rows (843:1133) from a certain variable (**spcfc_t** == "91017181") in my dataframe **neuedaten**. My syntax seems wrong. I would be very pleased for any help. Here is what I tried:

```
neuedaten3 <- neudaten[which(neudaten$spcfc_t == "91017181",],[c(-843:1133),]
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The minus is on wrong position. Try it without `which` and delete one comma. Set it like this:

```
neuedaten3<-neudaten[neudaten$spcfc_t == "91017181",][-c(843:1133),]
```

EDIT:
If you want to keep the rows that are not equal (spcfc_t == "91017181"), use:

```
neuedaten3 <- neudaten[-which(neudaten$spcfc_t == "91017181")[843:1133],]
```

Comment: thank you, that worked, I just noticed the result is not exactly what I expected: I want the new dataframe to keep all variables and additionally reduce the variabe 91017181 in length. The dataframe now only contains variable 91017181.

Comment: great! Thats exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!